# How to save SVG content as an SVG image on c# sever

Tags: c#, file, svg

Facing difficulty while saving svg content on C# server as an svg image file. I have generated and svg image and post the whole svg tag(included the vector image) to server. But after receiving on server, unable to save it as SVG image on server directory.

Client side code:

```
var imageData = resizedCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
var targetSVG = document.getElementById('svg');
var encodedString = encodeURIComponent($('#svgContainer')[0].innerHTML);
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/CanvasSave.aspx/UploadImage',
    data: '{ "imageData" : "' + encodedString + '", "userEmail": "' + userEmail + '" , "quantity": "' + quantity + '" }',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (msg) {....},
    error: function (xhr) {           
        alert('Error Occured! Please try again.\n\n Request Status: ' + xhr.status + ' Status Text: ' + xhr.statusText + ' ' + xhr.responseText);
    }
```

C# code:

```
public static string UploadImage(string imageData, string userEmail, int quantity)
{
    imageData = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(imageData);
    //Here complete svg tag with image data receive successfully. 
    //<svg id="svg" width="851" height="514" 
    //xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    //xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    //<image id="importedCanvas_0" xlink:href="data:image/pngbase64,iV...

    //From now on how can I save this imageData as an SVG file using c#

    string completePath = @"~\user-images\file.svg";

    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(completePath), FileMode.Create))
        {
            using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs))
            {

                byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(imageData);

                bw.Write(data);

                bw.Close();
            }

        }
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly does `escape` do? Does it really do base64? (If so, why at all? SVG is text, you can just put it into JSON.)

Comment: You  can't save on the server because you don't have the credential unless you are an admin.  You would need an application on server that runs with admin credentials to be able to save.  A webpage usually runs with a Guest Credentials that doesn't have write privileges.

Comment: @jdk What problem are you having exactly? Errors?

Comment: Thanks @Joey. Yes, I use the escape to encode the string. Bcoz in my knowledge it is necessary to encode image data into base64 string. Can you please suggest how can I save this into image file on server.

Comment: @jdweng, I didn't understand completely what you are talking about. Previously I have created image drawing using canvas and send them on server as pnd image. It will be great if you know how can I save vector image on server. thanks

Comment: There should be no differences between saving a vector image and a svg.  They are both binary files.  So the issue must be something else.  I'm not sure why you are using a base64 string and not UTF8.  Try changing the encoding.

Comment: @CathalMF I have update the get byte array code to this one. by using Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(imageData).  Got no error, only corrupt image generated. While opening in InkSpace it show 'link image was not found'. While opening in chrome it shows like this. [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0e6mAiJK5vqV2dWUDVtWTJlWGc)

Comment: @jdk How about opening the resulting file in a text editor and see what the difference is? SVG is just an xml structured file which can be viewed in any text editor.

Comment: There was encoding/decoding issue. I have update the code(shown above) and now it works fine. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

It's just text, so save it using regular text saving methods:

```
public static string UploadImage(string imageData, string userEmail, int quantity)
{
    imageData = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(imageData);

    var completePath = @"~\user-images\file.svg";
    completePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(completePath);

    File.WriteAllText(completePath, imageData);  // <--
}
```